# Laravel multiple hasmany relation limit issue

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, relation

I have 3 collection pages,posts,comments and relation is

pages => hasmany => posts => hasmany =>comments

**pages model relation**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PostsModel', 'page_id');
}
```

**posts model relation**

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CommentsModel', 'post_id')->limit(10);
}
```

**Query**

```
PagesModel::with('posts.comments')->get();
```

it supposes to take all page posts and 10 comments for each post, 
but it skips results, Many posts have multiple comments but unable to get comments.

Any solution or a better approach. Thanks

Comment: It's ok to me.  Is that your comments are deleted

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support for this in Laravel.

I created a package for it: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Use the `HasEagerLimit` trait in both the parent and the related model.

```php
class PostsModel extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}

class CommentsModel extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}
```

Then you can apply `->limit(10)` to your relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Its a common question for which there is no easy answer.  Read https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/ for an explanation